# SQL - Delete specific set of raw in a table using another table

Tags: sql, sql-delete, delete-row

Tabel 1 :

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | MainID | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1AX | VIC |
| 2 | B | Y | 2BY | SYD |
| 3 | C | W | 3CW | TAS |
| 4 | D | Z | 4DZ | TAS |

Tabel 2 :

| SALESID | QTY | AMT | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1AX | 1 | 100 | 2 |
| 2BY | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3CW | 3 |  | 5 |
| 4DZ | 3 | 12 | 2 |

Ignore other fields, I need to delete all raws in Tabel 1 where AMT in Tabel 2 has **zero or no value** for the SALESID.
For example, after the query, only raws containing 1AX & 4DZ should be remain in Tabel 1.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What if SlaesID = MainID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
delete from table1
    where exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where table1.mainid = t2.salesid and
                        (t2.amt = 0 or t2.amt is null)
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response, would you please explain to me the following part, please.   ( why 1 and t2) ;                                       
                 (select 1
                  from table2 t2

Comment: had to change the column headings, what if SlaesID = MainID

Comment: The "1" is because the `select` needs to return a column (in most databases) and the `t2` is a table alias which is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by subquery

- get all MainID from table2 where amt is 0 or null
- delete all rows that equal to previous fetched MainID

```sql
delete from table1 where MainID in (
    select SALESID from table2 where AMT <=0 or AMT is null
)
```

Comment: had to change the column headings, what if SlaesID = MainID

Comment: @J1987 it is easy to change subquery from `MainID` to `SALESID `,the name is just a symbol,you can change whatever you want,the value is important.I had update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thinking an INNER JOIN would be much faster on larger data sets. Something like this:

```
DELETE
    T1
FROM
    Table1 T1
INNER JOIN
    Table2 T2 ON T2.SalesID = T1.MainID
WHERE
    IsNull(T2.Amt,0) = 0
```